# CSV Parser works in windows, not linux

Tags: c++, linux, csv

I'm parsing a CSV file that looks like this:

```
E1,E2,E7,E8,,,
E2,E1,E3,,,,
E3,E2,E8,,,
E4,E5,E8,E11,,,
```

I store the first entry in each line in a string, and the rest go in a vector of strings:

```
while (getline(file_input, line)) {
    stringstream tokenizer; 
    tokenizer << line;
    getline(tokenizer, roomID, ',');
    vector<string> aVector;
    while (getline(tokenizer, adjRoomID, ',')) {
        if (!adjRoomID.empty()) {
            aVector.push_back(adjRoomID);
        }
    }
    Room aRoom(roomID, aVector);
    rooms.addToTail(aRoom);
}
```

In windows this works fine, however in Linux the first entry of each vector mysteriously loses the first character. For Example in the first iteration through the while loop:

`roomID` would be `E1` and `aVector` would be `2` `E7` `E8`

then the second iteration:
`roomID` would be `E2` and `aVector` would be `1` `E3`

Notice the missing E's in the first entry of aVector.

when I put in some debugging code it appears that it is initially being stored correctly in the vector, but then something overwrites it. Kudos to whoever figures this one out. Seems bizarre to me.

**EDIT:**
thank you Erik. I finally understand.  On windows all the lines just end with a \n. When I switch to Unix\Linux however, the lines end in \r\n. Thus, when `getline` reads a line it reads everything into the string including the \r. I was not accounting for this \r and it was screwing me up. The problem wasn't that the E was missing. It was that I had an extra entry in the vector with a single \r character in it. My other classes couldn't handle this entry with a single \r in it.

Comment: How did you open the file? In binary mode? I suspect that the CRLF hides the problem on Windows.

Comment: What compiler are you using on Windows?

Comment: Also your Room constructor/class body would be nice.

Comment: `rooms` is a linked list. I've confirmed with cout statements that aVector is borked before I pass it to the Room constructor and add it to the `rooms` linkedlist with the method addToTail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the \r in the windows \r\n linefeed could mess up the code doing your printing.

If you change to this if statement, does the problem disappear?

```
if (!adjRoomID.empty() && (adjRoomID[0] != '\r'))
```

EDIT: Fixed typo

Comment: `getline()` is platform independent.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: it's not `getline`, it's the stream that does automatic platform-specific line-end->`\n` conversion (on which the other functions rely), but this is disabled if you open the file in binary mode; that's why I asked how the file was opened in the comments.

Comment: Sorry about that typo, it should be \r not \\r - corrected answer

Comment: can you go into more detail on why it is messing up. I'm not quite getting it. what in my code is making it work for windows but not linux.

Comment: My bet is you're printing \r which only messes up what you display, your actual data (apart from an extra final string in the vector) would be correct.

Comment: it wasn't just the printing that was getting messed up. the whole program would crash. so it must be the extra final string in the vector. so does the extra final string just have the \r character in it?

Comment: Assuming a windows-generated CSV file, yes that should be it. Use e.g. `std::replace_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::bind2nd(std::less<char>(), 33), '?');` to replace all chars up to and including ascii 32 (space) with '?', then print the string and see if you have other funny characters

Answer (score 3):

**Oops**: misread your question, thought it was talking about not working on *Windows*.  I'm leaving the answer here in case anyone stumbles upon this in need of it, but I don't think it will help you (the asker) in this case.

If you're on MSVC6, you could be encountering [this bug](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q240015) with the getline function.  There's a fix in the link.

For posterity, here's the info from the link:

> SYMPTOM: "The Standard C++ Library template
>   getline function reads an extra
>   character after encountering the
>   delimiter. Please refer to the sample
>   program in the More Information
>   section for details."
>
> Modify the getline member function,
>   which can be found in the following
>   system header file string, as follows:

```
else if (_Tr::eq((_E)_C, _D))
            {_Chg = true;
          //  _I.rdbuf()->snextc(); /* Remove this line and add the line below.*/ 
              _I.rdbuf()->sbumpc();
            break; }
```

> **Note:** Because the resolution involves
>   modifying a system header file,
>   extreme care should be taken to ensure
>   that nothing else is changed in the
>   header file. Microsoft is not
>   responsible for any problems resulting
>   from unwanted changes to the system
>   header file

Comment: Wow. +1 to you, -1 to Microsoft. If Microsoft Bob didn't reach developers then Microsoft has Visual C++ 6 for them.

Comment: There are a number of dusty corners of STL where MSVC6's implementations are, at best, a bit flaky.  Newer MSVC's have pretty decent STL by comparison, and IMHO there are really very few excuses to still be running v6 in 2011.

Comment: How could he encounter this bug with MSVC6 on *linux* where he has the problem :)

Comment: Good catch, Erik!  Leaving the answer up in case someone ends up here with the platforms reversed, but hopefully someone will track down what's actually going on in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really what you're encountering, but Dinkumware posted a set of patches for the VC 5/6 library long ago. See: http://www.dinkumware.com/vc_fixes.html. Even if you haven't run into a problem (yet), it's probably worth applying the patches if you're going to use VC6.

Answer (score 0):

Try some cout debugging.  Print out the values as you read them in:

```
if (!adjRoomID.empty()) {
    cout << '"' << adjRoomId << '"' << endl;
    aVector.push_back(adjRoomID);
}
```

That will tell you if your strings are being read correctly from the get-go, and will also probably tell you if you're reading in extra weird characters from the file.